# #include <QtWidgets> not working in Qt 4

Tags: qt, qt5

A developer added a feature to our software using QtWidgets which as far as I can tell is a QT5 feature. The problem is that our software is still designed for QT4 and we cannot move to the latest version of QT just yet. The new feature works great when compiled in QT5 but when trying to compile using QT 4.8.5 brings up the following error.

```
src\qt\snapwidget.h:3: error: QtWidgets: No such file or directory
#include <QtWidgets>
                   ^
```

Is there any documentation on back porting QtWidgets to older version of QT? Perhaps someone was cooking up something like widgets before it made its way in as a native feature.

Comment: QtWidgets in Qt5 is QtGui in Qt4. You could use a macro to make the include dependent upon the Qt version.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Widgets are not a Qt 5 feature**. They are in Qt since day 1.

---

In general, I advise against using such per-module include. They will add *all* includes for the given module, raising your compilation times dramatically. Instead you can use

```
#include <QClass>
```

which will work just as well, and require only the adjustment to the `.pro` file I said below (*one* place, instead of modifying *all* source files).

---

Your problem is that there's no "QtWidgets" module in Qt 4. Widgets in Qt 4 were in the "gui" module.

Hence, the "equivalent" line in Qt 4 is

```
#include <QtGui>
```

You can use `QT_VERSION` to make your C++ code work in both Qt 4 and 5:

```
#include <QtGlobal>
#if QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 0, 0)
#  include <QtWidgets>
#else
#  include <QtGui>
#endif
```

Add a similar logic in the `.pro` file for linking against the `widgets` module. Both Qt 4 and Qt 5 by default link only the `core` and the `gui` modules, but as I've just said, that doesn't bring you widgets in Qt 5:

```
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4):QT += widgets
```